# Два вопроса: «Было» — какой член предложения? Корректна ли пунктуация?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксический-разбор, части-речи, члены-предложения

> — В тот день на ярмарке было заключительное шествие, и Тиммер сказала, что хочет побыть одна. Я хотела **было** объясниться, но она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть — она устала **(?)** и я могу оставить ее на час.
>   [Л. Пенни. Убийственно тихая жизнь](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=39927&p=63) (пер. с англ. Г. Крылова)

1. Каким членом предложения является "было"?
2. Правильна ли пунктуация в предложении? (Очень хочется на месте знака вопроса поставить запятую, или даже тире.) А как Вы видите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 7):

Я **хотела было** объясниться, но она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть – **она устала и я могу оставить ее на час.**

1) **Было – частица,** она относится к глаголу ***хотела*** и входит в состав сказуемого.  Можно посмотреть: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200100509

Употребляется для обозначения того, что действие началось или предполагалось, но было прервано или не завершилось. Пошел было, да 
остановился. Хотел было поехать, да не получилось. Стал было учителем, да не понравилось.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (история форм прошедшего времени) https://vuzlit.ru/845015/istoriya_form_proshedshego_vremeni

В дальнейшем в связи с развитием категории вида и лексических средств выражения различий протекания действия во времени **вспомогательный глагол преобразовался в неизменяемую частицу было.** Преобразовалось и значение **плюсквамперфекта:** данная форма стала обозначать действие, готовящееся в прошлом, но неосуществившееся или начавшееся в прошлом, но прерванное другим действием. Некоторые исследователи считают, что форма плюсквамперфекта сохраняется в некоторых севернорусских говорах, а также такие формы зафиксированы иногда в былинах, другие же придерживаются мнения, что в данных случаях мы имеем дело с синонимичными плюсквамперфекту конструкциями, а не формами плюс квамперфекта.

2) **Пунктуация в норме.** Тире используется для обозначения бессоюзной связи, поэтому при наличии союза И между предложениями запятая не ставится.

Если обособить двумя тире ***она устала***, то это не имеет смысла, так как предложения *ей нужно отдохнуть* и *она устала* равнозначны по смыслу (**вставка выглядит лишней**).

Comment: Отдельное спасибо за ссылку – то, что надо.

Comment: Мне кажется, что нужно переформулировать вопрос так:  _"Было" - часть речи и член предложения._ (У меня-то сначала были совсем другие предположения.) Как Вы считаете?

Comment: Наверное, лучше было бы сформулировать вопрос так: “Было” – часть речи и  член предложения?  Но я не уверена, что надо сейчас что-нибудь переделывать, так как обсуждение будет непонятным. Я посмотрела в учебнике значения и функции частиц, и там "было" относится  к формообразующим частицам и рассматривается в том же разделе, что и частица БЫ.  Я не уверена, что ответ "входит в состав сказуемого"  правилен. Частица БЫЛО тесно связана со вспомогательным глаголом: она придает ему определенное значение и уже вместе с ним (а не самостоятельно) входит в состав сказуемого. Но это не всем интересно.

Answer (score 4):

> ***Я хотела было объясниться, но она возразила...***
>
> “Было” – какой член предложения?

Какой член предложения? **Часть составного глагольного сказуемого** *хотела было объясниться.*

Comment: Было как  частица.  Например, здесь: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/752814

Comment: Простите, но вопрос был не о  **частях речи**, а о **членах предложения**.  Частица "было" в этом предложении является **частью сказуемого**.

Comment: Ну если только так. Пожалуй, я ее тоже включу в сказуемое для большей ясности. С другой стороны, а разве может эта частица относиться  не к сказуемому (не в данном, а в другом предложении)?

Comment: Кстати, Ваш ответ тоже не совсем точен, так как статус бывшей глагольной формы лучше указать, когда речь идет о составе сказуемого.

Comment: Напомню вопрос, заданный в теме: _“Было” – какой член предложения?_  Вот на этот  вопрос я и отвечал. Никакой неточности я в своём ответе не вижу! Извините, на этом всё.

Comment: Последнее замечание (на него не надо отвечать). Комментарии читаете не только Вы, но и другие участники форума, им я и объясню НЕТОЧНОСТЬ ОТВЕТА.  В современном языке форма "было" входит в составные сказуемые  разного вида в качестве связки, также эту форму можно отнести к устаревшему плюсквамперфекту,.Также не всем знакомо  ее точное значение и статус частицы. Я думаю, что  указать всё это  в ответе было бы не лишним.

Comment: Jasmin, если бы Вы всё это написали с самого начала в своём ответе, я бы вообще не полез в эту тему. Влез только из-за этого: вопрос -- "Какой член предложения?"; Ваш (бывший на то время)  ответ -- "Частица". _В огороде бузина, а в Киеве..."_

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с такой пунктуацией: **Я хотела было объясниться, но она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть – она устала и я могу оставить ее на час.**

Себе я объясняю это так. Она сказала, что ей нужно отдохнуть, а именно она сказала, что она устала и я могу оставить ее на час. Таким образом, тире отделяет пояснительную часть, которая состоит из двух простых предложений, соединенных союзом *и*. "Ей нужно отдохнуть" — общий член для обоих предложений в пояснительной части, поэтому запятая перед *и* не ставится.

Дополнение (после переписки с Alex_ander)

В моем варианте заметен несколько пренебрежительный тон: я устала, вы идите. К такому пониманию подталкивает союз *и*.

Но нельзя исключить также и предложенное Alex_ander толкование: *мне придётся пойти отдохнуть (я устала), так что и вы идите*. Тогда пунктуция такова:
**Я хотела было объясниться, но она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть – она устала — и я могу оставить ее на час.** Но при такой трактовке я бы, переводя этот отрывок на русский, поставил союз *а*: **Я хотела было объясниться, но она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть — она устала, `а` я (тем временем) могу оставить ее на час.** Звучит лучше, при этом запятая проводит границу между двумя  предложениями, оставляя вставку в первом предложении, и избавляет от необходимости ставить второе тире.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что в обозначенном месте нужно поставить **тире** - для оформления *вставки* (в более формальном контексте вместо пары тире подошли бы и скобки): пояснение "она устала" (почему понадобилось отдохнуть) *разрывает* естественную смысловую связь между *необходимостью отдохнуть и предложением расстаться*. Такое предложение связано с "усталостью" только через ранее названное её *следствие*, "уход на отдых". Без обозначения вставки воспринимается как не вполне логичное и невежливое "я устала, вы идите" или "я от вас устала".

Comment: Именно так я и понимаю: я устала, вы идите.  Обратите внимание на первую часть: она возразила. "Вы можете оставить меня на час" — это возражение на попытку объясниться.

Comment: Для меня это выглядит так: извините, мне придётся пойти отдохнуть (я устала), так что и вы идите.

Comment: Да, такое тоже возможно, я дополню и свой ответ.

Comment: Да, я рассуждала так же (вставка + тире). Но вижу ещё возможность: пропущенное "потому что" (тогда после "устала" необходима запятая), чтобы не было повторения.  **_... она возразила, что ей нужно отдохнуть – [потому что] она устала, и я могу оставить ее на час._** Можно ли ТАК трактовать, как Вы считаете?