# О предпрошедшем времени

Tags: глаголы

Приведу пример предпрошедшего времени в современном русском языке: "Я было хотел связаться с директором, но потом понял, что толку из этого не выйдет".

Является ли это лексическим приёмом или грамматическим?

Answer (score 1):

**Я было хотел связаться с директором, но потом понял, что толку из этого не выйдет.**

***Было*** в современном языке  является частицей, она относится к глаголу ***хотел*** и входит в состав сказуемого.  Употребляется для обозначения того, что **действие началось или предполагалось, но было прервано или не завершилось.** Пошел было, да остановился.

По происхождению ***было*** ― это  вспомогательный глагол, который раньше использовался для образования плюсквамперфекта (давнопрошедшего времени).

Подобный вопрос уже разбирался, можно посмотреть:  [Два вопроса: "Было" – какой член предложения? Корректна ли пунктуация?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441718/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/441719#441719)

Answer (score 1):

Ха! У Вас интересное восприятие этой формы.

> Хочу привести пример предпрошедшего времени в современном русском
>   языке: "Я было хотел связаться с директором, но потом понял, что толку
>   из этого не выйдет."

Вы, как я понимаю, "предпрошедшим" называете продолженное прошедшее?! То, что в английском называется "past perfect"?

В современном русском языке такого "предпрошедшего" времени нет, поскольку категория как таковая отсутствует, а ее частичный аналог - категория вида выражается не словоизменением, а словообразованием - и без вспомогательных глаголов. Собственно же перфект, без которого "предпрошедшее" невозможно представить, в русском исчез уже на этапе выделения русского из восточнославянской общности, то есть очень давно.

Да и по смыслу "[хотел] было" (такой порядок более естественен) выражает совсем другое - несостоявшееся или неудачно законченное действие. Возможно вас ввело в заблуждение то, что эту конструкцию, как и перфект  называют "незаконченным действием", это недоразумение, перфект это продолжающееся действие, а "прошедшее+было" - **неудачно** законченное.

Своим появлением эта форма обязана рудиментарно присутствовавшему в древнерусском языке "**давнопрошедшему** времени", которое прослеживается в украинском, но уже тоже как архаичная и поэтическая форма. Еще Ломоносов в XVIII веке находил давнопрошедшее и в русском. Но повторюсь, "давнопрошедшее" - это совсем не "предпрошедшее".

В современном русском семантика "давнопрошедшего" уже не актуальна. Это именно частица, а не вспомогательный глагол, и частица эта выражает значение несостоявшегося или неудачно завершенного действия.

У этой частицы, правда, есть одно интересное свойство. Она "проникает" сквозь модальный (или контектсно-модальный) глагол при котором находится. В вашем примере "хотел было позвонить" означает не то что действие "хотел" завершилось неудачно или не состоялось (подобное вообще невозможно представить для модального глагола), а то что говорящий не позвонил или не достиг цели своим звонком. И тут для изучающих РКИ может возникнуть большая проблема. Но эту проблему пока обходят стороной даже в формализованных описаниях корпусной грамматики.

> Является ли это лексическим приёмом или грамматическим?

Это вообще трудно назвать приемом или средством. Но это, конечно же, грамматическая конструкция, поскольку грамматика тут позволяет однозначно интерпретировать мысль, не прибегая к контексту. Так что если вам нужно считать это приемом, то грамматическим.